# Whitelist rejection error even after adding url to plist

Tags: iphone, cordova

This the error i am getting

```
ERROR whitelist rejection: url='https://ocrsdk.blob.core.windows.net/files/55fecc4c-b85f-42d6-b8ee-51cd8b40b081.result?se=2012-11-16T17%3A00%3A00Z&sr=b&si=downloadResults&sig=Y5kQg7cxt7CC4Eptd4bDlYg8%2FrJ5cA4n%2BfEkbgg6Hu8%3D'
2012-11-16 13:25:45.702 SnapAndPay[572:707] ERROR whitelist rejection: url='https://ocrsdk.blob.core.windows.net/files/55fecc4c-b85f-42d6-b8ee-51cd8b40b081.result?se=2012-11-16T17%3A00%3A00Z&sr=b&si=downloadResults&sig=Y5kQg7cxt7CC4Eptd4bDlYg8%2FrJ5cA4n%2BfEkbgg6Hu8%3D'
2012-11-16 13:25:45.705 SnapAndPay[572:707] ERROR whitelist rejection: url='https://ocrsdk.blob.core.windows.net/files/55fecc4c-b85f-42d6-b8ee-51cd8b40b081.result?se=2012-11-16T17%3A00%3A00Z&sr=b&si=downloadResults&sig=Y5kQg7cxt7CC4Eptd4bDlYg8%2FrJ5cA4n%2BfEkbgg6Hu8%3D'
```

This is the screenshot of my cordova plist file
[image: Screenshot of plist]
https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-LWaZkxIU9Xg/UKXzo8C5REI/AAAAAAAAAWU/23MyFdCmCxQ/s792/Screen%2520Shot%25202012-11-16%2520at%25201.29.50%2520PM.png

Comment: Just to get some more info, could you try with `*` and check if it works? And after that with `https://*.windows.net`?

Comment: @davids can you view the screenshot of the plist

Comment: BTW, it seems you are testing in iOS, aren't you? In that case, you should'n type the protocol. Try `*.windows.net`

Comment: thanks, will test it out. Yes i am testing in IOS

Comment: davis, can you post it in answer ,so that i could mark this as solved

.For me this one worked *.windows.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html), domain protocols are not supported by iOS, so you would remove them. Also, you should add the top level domain:

```
*.windows.net
```